# angular material error opening simple dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, module, angular-material, dialog

I am trying to learn Angular and receive an error opening dialog in my simple application. I have searched all over for the source of this error but cannot find the reason for it.

[image: Error Message]

App Module

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { MatListModule } from "@angular/material/list";
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { MatGridListModule } from "@angular/material/grid-list";
import { MatCardModule } from "@angular/material/card";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import "hammerjs";
import { MenuComponent } from "./menu/menu.component";
import { DishdetailComponent } from "./dishdetail/dishdetail.component";
import { DishService } from "./services/dish.service";
import { PromotionService } from "./services/promotion.service";
import { LeaderService } from "./services/leader.service";
import { HeaderComponent } from "./header/header.component";
import { FooterComponent } from "./footer/footer.component";
import { AboutComponent } from "./about/about.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { ContactComponent } from "./contact/contact.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing/app-routing.module";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    DishdetailComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    LoginComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatListModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  providers: [DishService, PromotionService, LeaderService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [LoginComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

HeaderComponent: The component that contains a button that will open the login form dialog.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";
import { LoginComponent } from "../login/login.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./header.component.scss"],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  openLoginForm() {
    this.dialog.open(LoginComponent, { width: "500px", height: "450px" });
  }
}
```

LoginComponent: The dialog component representing the login form

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Could you possibly create a StackBlitz demo to make working with the source code provided easier? My first bet would be, that you should add the parent component also inside the `entryComponents` field of your module.

Comment: Did you get any help from the code on https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview ?